# getRange getValues and length from a specific column for loop to stop at the correct row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have created a loop and I am having trouble making it stop at the correct row. 
In my spreadsheet, I have formulas that are shown as empty ("") when the formula meets certain criteria, but the `.length` is still identifying those cells as full of data (although no data is displayed in the cell), and therefore the loop runs longer than needed.

I either need the `.length` to NOT identify cells where data is not displayed, or alternatively I want to set the `.length` of the loop based on a specific column that I know has no such formulas that are creating a larger `.length`.

If I use the following code, it reads the cells with formulas as well and thus runs for too long.

```
   function makesCopiesOfTemplate_renamesTheCopies_PastesUrlAndIds() {
      var ssDataMadre = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1d6lw9R4WaPUCyHWcBRr8xDyZFjBNvUMH6BE_U2NXB8Q"); // PLANILLA DATA MADRE
      var sheetDataMadre = ssDataMadre.getSheets();
      var rangeDataMadre = sheetDataMadre[0].getDataRange();
      var valuesDataMadre = rangeDataMadre.getValues();

    // FOR loops STARTS here
      for (i=4;i<valuesDataMadre.length;i++) {
      namesPlanillas = valuesDataMadre[i][13];
      canEdit1 = valuesDataMadre[i][17];
      canEdit2 = valuesDataMadre[i][18];
      canEdit3 = valuesDataMadre[i][19];
      canComment1 = valuesDataMadre[i][20];
      canComment2 = valuesDataMadre[i][21];
      canComment3 = valuesDataMadre[i][22];
// Making a "copy of" the correct spreadsheet  
  var ssMateriaMadre = SpreadsheetApp.openById(urlTemplateMateria); // Activates "PLANILLA MATERIA MADRE"
  var sheetMateriaMadre = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); // Activates de Sheet within the above mentioned spreadsheet
  var destFolderForCopy = DriveApp.getFolderById(destFolderIDmaterias); //Identifies de destination folder, from Folder ID in the spreadsheet.
  var identifyFileToCopy = DriveApp.getFileById(ssMateriaMadre.getId()) // Identifies the file that has been activated above
  var copiedFile = identifyFileToCopy.makeCopy("GAS9_"+namesPlanillas, destFolderForCopy); // (1) Makes a copy of identified file. (2) Defines the name I want (3) Puts it in the correct folder.

/*  FUNCIONA, SOLO LO OCULTO PARA LAS PRUEBAS...
// Add Editors, Commenters & Viewers to the file. 
  var editFile = copiedFile.addEditor(canEdit1)
  var editFile = copiedFile.addEditor(canEdit2)
  var editFile = copiedFile.addEditor(canEdit3)
  var commentFile = copiedFile.addCommenter(canComment1)
  var commentFile = copiedFile.addCommenter(canComment2)
  var commentFile = copiedFile.addCommenter(canComment3)
  var viewFile = copiedFile.addViewer(canView1)
  var viewFile = copiedFile.addViewer(canView2)
  var viewFile = copiedFile.addViewer(canView3)
*/

// Get the URL of the CopiedFile (defined in "copiedFile" variable).
  var url = copiedFile.getUrl();
// Get the KEY of the CopiedFile (defined in "copiedFile" variable).
  var key = copiedFile.getId();

// Pastes the URL of the CopiedFile into column 7 of the 
  var pasteUrl = sheetDataMadre[0].getRange(i+1, 16);
  // SetValue escribe lo que le digamos, en el "range" que definimos arriba...
  pasteUrl.setValue(url);

// Copiar el KEY/ID del nuevo documento en la columna 8
  var pasteId = sheetDataMadre[0].getRange(i+1, 17);
  // SetValue escribe lo que le digamos, en el "range" que definimos arriba...
  pasteId.setValue(key);
  }
// FOR loop ENDS here
}
```

This is my attempt to define the length based on a different variable. This method still did not perform as desired and seems to get the `.length` of the entire sheet.

```
    function makesCopiesOfTemplate_renamesTheCopies_PastesUrlAndIds() {
      var ssDataMadre = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1d6lw9R4WaPUCyHWcBRr8xDyZFjBNvUMH6BE_U2NXB8Q"); // PLANILLA DATA MADRE
      var sheetDataMadre = ssDataMadre.getSheets();
      var rangeDataMadre = sheetDataMadre[0].getDataRange();
      var valuesDataMadre = rangeDataMadre.getValues();

//new variable trying to just get the values of COLUMN  B
      var valuesColumna_B_Materia = sheetDataMadre[0].getRange("B5:B2000").getValues(); 

     // FOR loops STARTS here
          for (i=4;i<valuesColumna_B_Materia.length;i++) {
          namesPlanillas = valuesDataMadre[i][13];
          canEdit1 = valuesDataMadre[i][17];
          canEdit2 = valuesDataMadre[i][18];
          canEdit3 = valuesDataMadre[i][19];
          canComment1 = valuesDataMadre[i][20];
          canComment2 = valuesDataMadre[i][21];
          canComment3 = valuesDataMadre[i][22];
// Making a "copy of" the correct spreadsheet  
  var ssMateriaMadre = SpreadsheetApp.openById(urlTemplateMateria); // Activates "PLANILLA MATERIA MADRE"
  var sheetMateriaMadre = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); // Activates de Sheet within the above mentioned spreadsheet
  var destFolderForCopy = DriveApp.getFolderById(destFolderIDmaterias); //Identifies de destination folder, from Folder ID in the spreadsheet.
  var identifyFileToCopy = DriveApp.getFileById(ssMateriaMadre.getId()) // Identifies the file that has been activated above
  var copiedFile = identifyFileToCopy.makeCopy("GAS9_"+namesPlanillas, destFolderForCopy); // (1) Makes a copy of identified file. (2) Defines the name I want (3) Puts it in the correct folder.

/*  FUNCIONA, SOLO LO OCULTO PARA LAS PRUEBAS...
// Add Editors, Commenters & Viewers to the file. 
  var editFile = copiedFile.addEditor(canEdit1)
  var editFile = copiedFile.addEditor(canEdit2)
  var editFile = copiedFile.addEditor(canEdit3)
  var commentFile = copiedFile.addCommenter(canComment1)
  var commentFile = copiedFile.addCommenter(canComment2)
  var commentFile = copiedFile.addCommenter(canComment3)
  var viewFile = copiedFile.addViewer(canView1)
  var viewFile = copiedFile.addViewer(canView2)
  var viewFile = copiedFile.addViewer(canView3)
*/

// Get the URL of the CopiedFile (defined in "copiedFile" variable).
  var url = copiedFile.getUrl();
// Get the KEY of the CopiedFile (defined in "copiedFile" variable).
  var key = copiedFile.getId();

// Pastes the URL of the CopiedFile into column 7 of the 
  var pasteUrl = sheetDataMadre[0].getRange(i+1, 16);
  // SetValue escribe lo que le digamos, en el "range" que definimos arriba...
  pasteUrl.setValue(url);

// Copiar el KEY/ID del nuevo documento en la columna 8
  var pasteId = sheetDataMadre[0].getRange(i+1, 17);
  // SetValue escribe lo que le digamos, en el "range" que definimos arriba...
  pasteId.setValue(key);
  }
// FOR loop ENDS here
}
```

Comment: The code isn't complete. See [mcve].

Comment: Sorry Ruben, you can now see the FULL CODE. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced similar problems. The issue comes from where you define a range. When you tell the code to look for the data range, that includes formulas. I would suggest using `Logger.log()` to view the `.getValues` array you create. This will help know how to define where you want to stop.

As a potential solution, you will need to reference a column that will always have data in it if there is row data, as well as not use a formula. A timestamp for form submissions is a good place to start. You can also have conditional formatting (for backgrounds, font colors, borders, etc) on one of your columns and have your code look for the rows that have been formatted, instead of if they have data.

For instance, if the row has data, color this cell green. Tell your code to loop through that column and if green, perform code. If not, `continue`  or stop. This will give you a more accurate range of your data and allow you to more precisely control when your code runs.

Comment: Thanks MasterCrander, although I am a rookie with coding, I believe I understand your suggestion BUT the problem is that I am having trouble setting the loop that a single column...As you can see i the second code I posted on the original question, I have tried with "var valuesColumna_B_Materia = sheetDataMadre[0].getRange("B5:B2000").getValues();" but its not working and the .lenght is taken for the entire sheet..

Comment: Yes, that is what you need to change. You've created a 2D array of nearly 2000 rows. You need to look at the GAS documentation for ranges and reference a column that _does not_ have formulas but _does_ have data, OR a column that _does_ have a conditional formatting to check. You can find range definition documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet) and range qualities documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)

Comment: Thank you gain MasterCrander... If I ever manage to do it I will post back here as I couldnt find a good example of how this is done online. If I learn how ... :)